# Shipping Label Creation - ShipWorks Alternative in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

New to Magento and slightly confused on the shipping process. It seems most people use a shipping solution of either a Desktop client or cloud based solution. Similar to ShipWorks or ShipStation.

I am looking for a Magento extension to be an alternative to these products that would seamlessly integrate with the Magento admin panel. I Seem to be having trouble locating one.

What is the best way to manage shipping and label creation with UPS and USPS?  Are Solutions like ShipWorks and ShipStation the best methods?

Comment: Are you looking for an end to end automated solution? You can enter the shipping information in the backend.

Comment: I know you can just type in the tracking number. What I am looking to do is to be as automated as possible. For instance an order comes in and I just want to hit print label and it will print a label and update tracking all in one sweep!

Comment: Out of the box this isn't possible. If you haven't had any luck in magento-connect then you need a custom module built. GL

Comment: Im hoping someone knows of a solution that is already built!

Comment: Ans also if this doesn't currently exist what is the next best thing?

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of labelling solutions out there, some are integrated and run as extensions, and others are SAAS based like ShipStation/ShipWorks. I'm aware that ShippingEasy has an extension where it adds a button in the Magento Admin from where you can ship, maybe this is an option.

It really depends on how many orders you are getting as to what you need here. There is built in labelling from the Magento admin aswell, so for UPS/FedEx these are good options if have low volume.